# Extract specific part of a TXT file in CMD/Batch

Tags: batch-file

I have a txt file which is the output of an earlier command.
Here's what that txt file looks like:

```
Uploading file 'Temp/output.mp4'...


Progress:     6.00 Mbps, 327680 / 10034413 (3.266%) ETA   14.82s

Progress:     5.85 Mbps, 999424 / 10034413 (9.960%) ETA   12.84s

Progress:     5.49 Mbps, 1687552 / 10034413 (16.818%) ETA   12.26s

Progress:     5.21 Mbps, 2310144 / 10034413 (23.022%) ETA   11.56s

Progress:     5.44 Mbps, 3014656 / 10034413 (30.043%) ETA   10.44s

Progress:     5.28 Mbps, 3686400 / 10034413 (36.738%) ETA    9.48s

Progress:     4.62 Mbps, 4161536 / 10034413 (41.473%) ETA    9.06s

Progress:     4.79 Mbps, 4849664 / 10034413 (48.330%) ETA    8.02s

Progress:     4.95 Mbps, 5439488 / 10034413 (54.208%) ETA    7.12s

Progress:     5.77 Mbps, 6242304 / 10034413 (62.209%) ETA    5.78s

Progress:     5.27 Mbps, 6897664 / 10034413 (68.740%) ETA    4.78s

Progress:     5.29 Mbps, 7553024 / 10034413 (75.271%) ETA    3.78s

Progress:     5.13 Mbps, 8159232 / 10034413 (81.312%) ETA    2.86s

Progress:     4.82 Mbps, 8749056 / 10034413 (87.191%) ETA    1.98s

Progress:     5.36 Mbps, 9469952 / 10034413 (94.375%) ETA    860ms

Progress:     4.62 Mbps, 10034413 / 10034413 (100.000%) ETA       0s
Upload successful! Video ID: XXXXXXXXXXX
Thumbnail uploaded!
```

I'd like to extract the XXXXXXXXXXX into a variable.

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
I should mention that the XXXXXXXXXXX will be different everytime :) incase it wasn't obvious.

UPDATE:
Finally got where I wanted with this:

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %%A in ('type log.txt ^| findstr "Video ID"') do set youtube=%%A
```

Comment: What have you tried, where are you stuck? Did you have a look at the [`for /F` loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) to read the text file and [`find`](https://ss64.com/nt/find.html) or [`findstr`](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html) to search and extract specific lines?

Comment: I would recommend avoiding the pain of text parsing in `cmd.exe` and use PowerShell instead.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the InFile is `Log.txt` in current folder, 
the following batch will

1. extract lines starting with `Upload`
2. parse those lines with `for /f`, splitting them at the chars `:` or `'` into two parts
3. checking if the first part is either `Uploading file` or `Upload successful! Video ID` and store the 2nd part into vars File/VideoID respectively.

---

```
:: Q:\Test\2019\07\30\SO_57263881.cmd
@Echo off
Set "InFile=.\log.txt"
Set "File="
Set "VideoID="

for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=':" %%A in (
  'findstr /I "^Upload" ^<"%InFile%"'
) Do if "%%A" equ "Uploading file " (
  Set "File=%%B" 
) else if "%%A" equ "Upload successful! Video ID" Set "VideoID=%%B"
if defined File if Defined VideoID (
  Echo File   : %File%
  Echo VideoID: %VideoID:~1%
)
```

Sample output:

````
> Q:\Test\2019\07\30\SO_57263881.cmd
File   : Temp/output.mp4
VideoID: XXXXXXXXXXX```
````

Comment: Hi LotPings, thank you for your response. This doesn't seem to work. At first it couldn't find the file until I replaced %inFile% with !inFile! but now it just shows nothing. It never completes the command. I'm relatively new to this so I want to apologise if I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: Using `!InFile!` should only be neccessary when setting **and*** using a variable inside a (code block), what isn't the case in *your* sample code (and also requires a `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` in front) . To debug batch files, run them from within an open cmd window to see what is output, or append a pause command to the end of the batch.

Comment: Ah I should have mentioned, this whole thing will be running from inside a FOR loop and I use enabledelayedexpansion

Comment: I ended up using for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %%A in ('type log.txt ^| findstr "Video ID"') do set youtube=%%A

Comment: The var youtube will still have a leading space then. findstr can directly read a file (or as I did via redirection).

Comment: It did have an extra space but I used !youtube:~1! to remove it. So far it's the only method I found which works reliably.